# ASP.NET Core project referencing a .NET project fails to build with msbuild

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have the follow set of projects in my solution: 
1) A .NET framework (4.7.1) project that produces an assembly. "Project A" 
2) A ASP.NET core MVC based web api project based on .NET Core 2.1. "Project B"

Project B references Project A, building the solution via Visual Studio 2017 does not lead to any issues. However if I try and build the solution via msbuild using the following command, I am unable to compile Project B:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe"
>   D:\Stuff\MySolution.sln" /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Debug /v:m
>   /clp:Summary
>
> Errors in D:\Stuff\ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj 
>     Unable to resolve
>   'D:\Stuff\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'
>   
>   Unable to resolve 'D:\Stuff\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj for
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1 (win-x64)'

ProjectB's property group looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
 <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
 <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
 <ProjectGuid>{D41E3CAE-2EE3-4BED-8965-50AF8C243A20}</ProjectGuid>
 <RootNamespace>com.ProjectB</RootNamespace>
 <AssemblyName>com.ProjectB</AssemblyName>
 <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And also has the following PackageReference:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

It is as if MSBuild is trying to apply the target framework defined in ProjectB to ProjectA, however as mentioned before this does not happen in Visual Studio.

Comment: Why do you want a .NET Core project to depend on a .NET Framework project? https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Comment: The plan is to eventually move it to core as well but initially it has to stay .NET based.

Comment: Given that, you created a wrong .NET Core project. Please try again to create an ASP.NET Core project targeting .NET Framework. However, keep in mind that ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework is no longer supported on .NET Core 3 and above.

Comment: @Lex Li But the question is why does it work fine if I compile it via Visual Studio? It runs fine and I can debug it etc. The only thing that does not work is compiling it via MSbuild so I am probably not configuring something correctly I assume?

Comment: That's not unexpected either, as VS does not run MSBuild the way you thought. If you want the two to work the same way, report this issue to Microsoft and let them fix that.

Comment: Can you try passing `/restore` to msbuild as well? I suggest changing the .net project to .net standard or multittargeting to .net framework and .net standard. Also make sure you are using the latest VS 2017 version (15.9.*) as a bug in this area has been fixed in 15.8

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload the sample project to GitHub or something? Also, try building your project B with `msbuild /restore ProjectB.csproj`. Which version of NuGet are you using? Try updating that as well

Comment: You did not write in the question the dependencies of the projects. In addition, I think you should add the rest of Project B's `csproj` file to the question.

Comment: Hi , any update for this issue? If you've got the answer from the comments above you can add it as answer. And please check if Baruch's answer can resolve your question, you can consider marking it as answer if it's an answer to your question:)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Unfortunately I was never able to find a proper solution to the issue, so I ended up converting the .NET Core project to a regular .NET framework project, this made it work on MSBuild, the original issue still persists so I can't really offer an answer.

Comment: @user1628056 Sorry but I can't reproduce same issue in my machine. Please try updating your vs to latest 15.9.13 and try if it helps. Also, if same issue persists, I think something is wrong with your solution file or proj file: 1. you can create a new solution and add two empty .net fx and .net core projects to check if this issue persists 2. You can share a simple sample(**after deleting the code in it**) with similar issue by one-drive or github so that I can check it directly

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems that **Project B** depend on **Project A**.

**You can't reference to a .NET Framework project from .NET Core project.** And this sis an answer.

Now, why in Visual Studio it can build? There may be missing details in the question, or the compilation is not the same compilation that you are trying to perform.